# How to use multiple data frame inputs for Mapdeck add_scatterplot within R Shiny?

Tags: r, shiny, mapdeck

I'm finding [Mapdeck](https://symbolixau.github.io/mapdeck/articles/mapdeck.html) to be a really cool alternative mapping method when working with large datasets in r shiny.  However I'm finding it difficult to pass in multiple datasets in order to expand the complexity of the resulting map.

For Example: I'm trying to populate the tooltip to create a popup with 'two' items by pulling in information from a second data frame (to illustrate a 1-to-many relationship).  But I can't get it to work.  Any thoughts?

Data sample

```
Map_DF <- data.frame("Point_ID" = 1:3, "Latitude" = c(38.05, 39.08, 40.05), "Longitude" = c(-107.00, -107.05, -108.00))
PointUse_DF <- data.frame("Point_ID" = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 3), "PointUse" = c("farm", "house", "farm", "house", "farm"))
```

The Code.

```
# ################################################################################################
# ################################################################################################
# # Sec 1a. Needed Libaries & Input Files

library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(mapdeck)
library(dplyr)


################################################################################################
################################################################################################
#UI
ui <- dashboardPage(
    dashboardHeader(), 
    dashboardSidebar(), 
    dashboardBody(
        mapdeckOutput(outputId = 'mapA')
    )
)

################################################################################################
################################################################################################
server <- function(input, output) {


    ##The MapDeck Token
    key <- '## put your own token here ##'
    set_token(key) ## set your access token


    ### The Map
    output$mapA <- renderMapdeck({
     mapdeck() %>%
            add_scatterplot(
                data = Map_DF, 
                lat = "Latitude",
                lon = "Longitude",
                layer_id = 'Point_ID',
                tooltip = c("Point_ID",
                             PointUse_DF$PointUse[Map_DF$Point_ID]  # the idea of passing in a a key and returning multiple items
                            )
             )
    })

}

################################################################################################
################################################################################################
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 1):

The tooltip renders a column of the `data` object inside the popup.
So whatever you want displayed in the popup has to already exist on the data

with your example you need to create the tooltip column

```
# Using data.table to rshape the data to give a comma-separated list of 'PointUse' values
library(data.table)

dt <- setDT( PointUse_DF )[, .(info = paste0(PointUse, collapse = ", ")), by = Point_ID]

## Now you can put this onto the map object

Map_DF <- merge(
  x = Map_DF
  , y = dt
  , by = "Point_ID"
  , all.x = T
)

mapdeck() %>%
  add_scatterplot(
    data = Map_DF, 
    lat = "Latitude",
    lon = "Longitude",
    layer_id = 'Point_ID',
    radius_min_pixels = 3,
    tooltip = "info"
    )
  )
```

[image]

Comment: Hmm, okay.  Which I guess if it has to come from a column within the single data entry, it can be from a list at least.  Good to know, and that solves this case example.

Comment: It is possible to expand upon this 'list' idea?  Maybe with a reactive function within the shiny environment?  

Some other use cases I'm trying to solve include 'coloring the point by PointUse (e.g., farm = red, house = blue, farm & house = first red then blue if filtered) & implementing reactive functions based on inputs$ filters from the shiny app (e.g., only show those points related with 'house', etc etc).


Alot of the issues I'm trying to address come down to how to handle that 1-to-many relationship from my data while using MapDeck to plot the sites.

Comment: Can you open an issue on the github page so we can discuss it there? It will be easier, and more appropriate than this comment section.

Comment: Sure.  Followed up with a similar comment as an issue.